# Passing PIL PngImageFile to tensorflow for image recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, python-imaging-library

I take an image in from the user and I want to pass it to tensorflow to determine what is in it:

```
 @app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
 def upload_file():
  if request.method == 'POST':
   f = request.files['file']
   f.save(f.filename)
   i = Image.open(f)
   image_handler(i)

def image_handler(image):
 create_graph()
 print("Model loaded")

node_lookup = NodeLookup()
print("Node lookup loaded")

print("Img: ")
print(image)
predictions = dict(run_inference_on_image(image))
print(predictions)
return jsonify(predictions=predictions)
```

image_handler() is using the functions and the NodeLookup class from the tensorflow imagenet repo found here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py

The problem is when I run the app it will load fine, the user can select an image fine too but when they hit submit it get the following error when getting the predictions:

```
Expected binary or unicode string, got <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=200x200 at 0x243126ABA90>
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling run_inference_on_image with the PngImageFile object returned by Image.open. But run_inference_on_image expects a file name.